# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked at a lot of topics in this topic, but I'm not able to adapt the code in my own code. Because there's obviously a mistake I can't see. And I'm getting the error.

**EpisodeModel.class**

public class EpisodeModel {

```
private String episode;

public EpisodeModel(String episode) {
    this.episode = episode;
}

public EpisodeModel()
{

}

public String getEpisode() {
    return episode;
}

public void setEpisode(String episode) {
    this.episode = episode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EpisodeModel{" +
            "episode='" + episode + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

**MyFragment.class**

```
public void check() {
        ref.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Watched").child(seriesTitle).child("Season").child(seasonGet)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        EpisodeModel episodeModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(EpisodeModel.class);
                        Log.i("child",episodeModel.toString());

                        Log.i("test","test2");
                        String st = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        int no = Integer.parseInt(st);

                        if(!deneme.contains(no))
                        {
                            deneme.add(no);
                        }

                        checkModelTestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


...onChildChanged..onChildRemoved..onChildMoved..onCancelled..}};
```

**Logcat**

```
Process: com.example.forev.seriesboiler, PID: 6959
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.example.forev.seriesboiler.Models.EpisodeModel
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.forev.seriesboiler.Fragments.SeriesDetailsFragment$1.onChildAdded(SeriesDetailsFragment.java:88)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Comment: dataSnapshot contains a Boolean, so dataSnapshot.getValue(EpisodeModel.class) causes a casting exception. You need to figure out why it comes back a Boolean and not as your EpisodeModel object.

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

> EpisodeModel episodeModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(EpisodeModel.class);

In this line, you are getting the error that says Boolean object can't be converted to EpisodeModel. This may appear if you have set the value of that child to **true** or **false** (*Without double quotes*). See it again and try to add a double quote around the **"true"** or **"false"** that you want to set to the child value.